# return the base word without POS tags

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy

Is there in anyway to stem both words (watching and watchers) to "watch" without using POS tagging?

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize('watchers', pos='n')
wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize('watching', pos='v')
```

This and English Stemmer mentioned below both return ('watcher', 'watch'). I need to return only ('watch') using nltk or spacy.

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import EnglishStemmer
stemmer = EnglishStemmer()
stemmer.stem('watchers') , stemmer.stem('watching')
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Lancaster Stemmer* from *NLTK* will return the desired result. There are plenty of stemmers in *NLTK* which differentiate by the rules they use.

```
from nltk.stem import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

print stemmer.stem("watching"), stemmer.stem("watchers")
>watch watch
```

As can be seen from [NLTK-Lancaster_Stemmer](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/lancaster.html) the rule is:

```
"re2>",      # -er > -
```

Unlike *Lancaster Stemmer*, the *Snowball Stemmer* does not use this rule so **-er suffix** is addressed from different points of view in these stemmers.
For example both works correct when **-er** comes after a vowel. *Lancaster Stemmer* fails for most of the verbs ending with **consonent + -er** like *sever*, *aver*, etc. 
[verbs that end in -er](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/words/erv.html)

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk.stem import LancasterStemmer

snowball_stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
lancaster_stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

print snowball_stemmer.stem("beer"), lancaster_stemmer.stem("beer")
>beer beer

print snowball_stemmer.stem("aver"), lancaster_stemmer.stem("aver")
>aver av
```